# How to change Rails default time format?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using this guide, http://blog.nicoschuele.com/posts/cheatsheet-to-set-app-wide-date-and-time-formats-in-rails, and it doesn't seem to be working.

Currently, whenever I make a JSON request and get back data my `created_at` and other time fields show `iso8601` format.

An example of the format is `2014-10-23T00:35:14.800Z`. I would prefer something more readable like `Sun, 3 Nov 2013 14:22:18 -0700`

I did what the guide above said to do, but when I restart my server and fire off the request again, the JSON still returns the data in `iso8601` format.

How do I remedy this?

Comment: You do not want to change the time format in the API. Keep it as ISO 8601, and change it on the client side. Way less hassle all around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend it but you can set it Rails wide as you've requested at this link: http://blog.nicoschuele.com/posts/cheatsheet-to-set-app-wide-date-and-time-formats-in-rails

---

I'll give you what I used for my html DateTime conversion.  I do not have a JSON answer, but I hope this'll give you the answer you're looking for.  I agree with *Nils Landt* in

> You do not want to change the time format in the API. Keep it as ISO 8601, and change it on the client side. Way less hassle all around.

Here's what I put in my controller:

```
before_action :correct_datetime, only: [:create, :update]
def correct_datetime
  params['event']['starts_at'] = DateTime.strptime(params['event']['starts_at'],'%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p') unless params['event'].try {|i| if i.try(:has_key?, 'starts_at'); i['starts_at'].empty?; else; true; end }
  params['event']['ends_at'] = DateTime.strptime(params['event']['ends_at'],'%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p') unless params['event'].try {|i| if i.try(:has_key?, 'ends_at'); i['ends_at'].empty?; else; true; end }
end
```

And in my view I'm using [Bootstrap DateTimePicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) for some text areas.

```
Starts at: <%= f.text_field :starts_at, value: (f.object.starts_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p') if f.object.starts_at), class: 'form-control', style: 'width:300px;' %>
Ends at: <%= f.text_field :ends_at, value: (f.object.ends_at.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %l:%M %p') if f.object.ends_at), class: 'form-control', style: 'width:300px;' %>
```

To allow the datetime picker to work I use the following in my **event.js.coffee** CoffeeScript file:

```
$ ->
  $("#event_starts_at").datetimepicker()
  $("#event_ends_at").datetimepicker()
  return
```

I apologize that I don't have the JSON results for this.  But I have given you the input and output formatting methods for accomplishing what you seek.

To convert from a DateTime object from the DB you use `strftime`.  And to format it back to save in the DB you use `strptime`.